# Can I change the styles of the last p only with CSS?

Tags: css

I've got several p tags in the content of a page. I want to change the color of the last one before the div that hold them. Can I do this just with CSS?

```
<div class="text">
   <p>P One</p>
   <p>P Two</p>
   <p>P Three</p>
   <p>P Four (this is the one I'd like to modify)</p>
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The easy, portable way:

```
<p class="last">P Four (this is the one I'd like to modify)</p>

.text p.last {}
```

The easy, less-portable way uses [:last-child](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#last-child-pseudo):

```
.text p:last-child {}
```

Or [:last-of-type](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#last-of-type-pseudo):

```
.text p:last-of-type {}
```

Comment: Here's a support chart for `:last-child`: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-lastchild

Comment: Thanks Roger! I'll use the second example because I'm loading the text dynamically